# Книга для крупных проектов на PHP

Tags: php, книги

Посоветуйте книгу по web-программированию, где описаны громоздкие проекты: как составлять, как работать, короче говоря, практикум.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-php)

Answer (score 3):

- Джек Д. Харрисон "PHP. Трюки" - там проект социальной сети.
- Дэвид Скляр и Адам Трахтенберг "PHP сборник рецептов".
- Уильям С. "75 готовых решений для вашего web-сайта на PHP (Самоучитель)".

Comment: Спасибо сборник рецептов читал, отличная книга, но только на английском читал. Попробую PHP трюки прочитать, посмотрим, что нового.

Comment: У меня есть и на русском, могу скинуть по мылу.

Comment: Спасибо, я читал. Сейчас просматриваю PHP трюки, хорошая книга, норм. Но жаль, что там ООП не встретить. Может я не встретил пока что, но в содержании не видел.

Comment: Это список книг, которыми я пользуюсь. ООП есть в книге Робин Никсон "PHP, MySQL и JavaScript" в пятой главе.

Comment: Читал но не до конца хорошо значит над прочитать всё проверим спасибо большое.

Comment: Дааа PHP трюки книга сложноватая особенно когда всё очень сложно устроено даже в 3 трюке отпадает желание читать не для слабонервных))

Comment: Никто не говорил, что будет легко.

Answer (score 1):

Может лучше начать с небольших и наращивать постепенно? Ведь проекты становятся гомоздкими только после увеличения каких то начальных свойств данных и т.д.

Comment: Да можно.Возможно.Но с чего начать какой проект создать чтоб он впоследствии громоздским стал очень сложным какие нибудь идеи есть какую задачу выполнить?